# git clone modifying eclipse C/C++ project include paths

Tags: c++, c, eclipse, git

I am working on al large C/C++ project using eclipse; to keep track of changes, I am periodically saving backups of the the whole eclipse workspace to .tar files. I wanted to start using git to keep track of changes in my workspace instead.

I have created a git repository and added my whole workspace to it. 
I then cloned the git repository and opened the cloned workspace with Eclipse. 
The cloned workspace will not compile: inspecting in the project properties, the include paths are changed with respect to what i see in the original workspace.

I then tried manually copying the original workspace folder and opening the copied workspace in Eclipse. In this case the all the paths are correct and my code compiles just like in the original workspace.

What may be the problem? when a whole folder is under git, what is the difference between git clone and a simple copy excluding what happens in the .git folder?

Answer (score 0):

Empty folders were not copied over to the cloned workspace and seem to be causing the problems in the workspace include paths configuration.

Including the folders by adding a dummy .gitkeep file in each solved the problem.